# check and view reply for sent email - PHP - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, wamp

I am using php and Codeigniter, I need to implement the following schema

[image]

for list of emails I need to send emails for them, and if they reply to this email, I need to know if the reply and what the content of this reply and view it using my php project.

Also I need to send them a multiple choice question and they have to chose one option as answer, and then check this answer from my php project.

I can send email from my gmail, but can't send it from the wamp server itself.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly familiar with CodeIgniter, but if you want to send an email, and it doesn't work, especially on Windows the common problem is that there is no SMTP server configured.

Most *nix distros have some form or another of a SMTP server running by default, Windows doesn't. When unconfigured PHP assumes localhost to be an SMTP server.

This SMTP server is what PHP needs to be able to send emails, so you'll either have to configure one or find one you can use that's provided by someone else.

For using PHP's native mail() function and any library that relies on it the configuration entries you're looking for are SMTP and smtp_port. (Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

It might very well be that your ISP provides a SMTP server. Otherwise you can always set up a gmail/hotmail/whatever account and use their SMTP settings. This is usually far easier than setting up your own server.

If you choose to set one up yourself, you'll want to look into SPF, so your messages don't get marked as spam by default.